# wildfly 10 performance tunning

Tags: performance, wildfly-10

I am using a WildFly 10.1.0.Final to learn developing J2EE applications and I managed finally to deploy a working EAR application into it :-)

The purpose of this application is only to store 'echo' messages comming from divers clients, into a PostgreSQL database.

This EAR contains an EJB module, a WEB module and JPA module. I am using a single stateless EJB3 (EchoBean, having a remote interface), from the WEB tier and an external client also. There is also an MDB, what handles the received JMS messages and calls the same EchoBean to store them.

Using JMS (MDB -> EJB3 -> JPA) 50000 messages are store in 250 - 300 seconds but using the remote client (remote -> EJB3 -> JPA) the same number of messages are stored in 3500 - 4000 seconds.

Could somebody tell me how to change the WildFly settings in order to have a better performance? Currently, I am using the standalone-full configuration.

Thank you.